# Find out from an object as an interface whose instance it is

Tags: reflection, d

I have the following scenario (https://run.dlang.io/is/19OOW9):

```
import std.stdio;

void main(string[] args)
{
    inter1 c1 = new foo();
    foo c2 = new foo();
    writeln("Origin=interface: ", typeof(c1).stringof);
    writeln("Origin=class: ", typeof(c2).stringof);
}

interface inter1 {
}

class foo : inter1 {
}
```

I work with interfaces and have different implementations for them. Now I need to know which concrete implementation is currently being used. So in the example above, I would like to know from `c1` that it is an instance of the class `foo`.

Is this possible in the language D?

I have already tried the possibilities of `object` (e.g. `TypeInfo_Class`) and `std.traits`. Unfortunately without success.

A workaround is, of course, to provide the interface with a suitable meta method (https://run.dlang.io/is/Xnt0TO):

```
import std.stdio;

void main(string[] args)
{
    inter1 c1 = new foo();
    foo c2 = new foo();
    writeln("Origin=interface: ", c1.strategyName);
    writeln("Origin=class: ", c2.strategyName);
}

interface inter1 {
    @property string strategyName() const;
}

class foo : inter1 {
    @property string strategyName() const {
        return "foo";
    }
}
```

However, this is cumbersome and unusual for D. I can well imagine that there is a better implementation of this.

Best regards

Thorsten

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is quite simple actually: first cast to `Object`, then fetch the `typeid`, after a `null` check:

```
Object o = cast(Object) your_object;
if(o is null) { /* i don't think this ever happens but you should check anyway */ }
writeln(typeid(o)); // will tell the class name
```

If you want to call a method on a specific class, you can just cast directly to your class, and again, null check it.

The intermediate cast to Object allows the typeid (aka classinfo) to succeed, whereas calling it directly on an interface always returns the typeid of the interface itself. This is because a D interface is defined to be very thin for maximum compatibility with other languages and doesn't automatically assume run time type information is actually present through it. But the cast to Object tells it you are assuming the RTTI is present, and then typeid will pull it.

Note that the typeid data doesn't provide a whole lot of information... it is mostly just what's needed for dynamic cast, comparison, and other features of the language runtime. But one convenience method it has is a class name and toString methods, which is why the writeln succeeds. But if you're looking for more detailed runtime reflection, you'll have to do it with a CT bridge function, or probably better yet, just write your own methods in the interface.

But if all you need is the class name, use that toString. It gives the fully-qualified name, including module name, so instead of `foo`, you will get like `yourmodule.foo`. You can just cut that off if you like by slicing at the dot.